# Issues in nodejs core: HTTP parser is eating all the cycles

Tags: node.js

I am trying to diagnose  a bug in my node.js application. The problem is that, after leaving the node.js process running overnight, we consistently run into a situation where the HTTP parser in node core ends up devouring all CPU cycles and locking up the process. I know that it's the HTTP parser, because I've traced it with dtrace.

Please consider the following quick and dirty flamegraph visualization:

```
http://37.153.104.73:8081/main.html
```

This visualization uses the technique described here. The slider at the top adjusts the hour when the trace was taken. The column on the left is the time spent in my application code, and the column on the right is the time spent by the HTTP parser. You can see that over the course of the night, more and more time is spent in the HTTP parser, until 3:00am, where literally all of the time is spent in the HTTP processor.

Perhaps one thing that might be causing this is we are using the eventsource-node library, which sets up long-lived HTTP connections.

This problem occurs on Node.js 0.8 and 0.10, on 32-bit Linux, 64-bit Linux, and SmartOS.

I don't have any experience diagnosing issues that originate in node core, so any guidance as to how to get started diagnosing this would be greatly appreciated. All of the trace data is available on the server I linked to above.

Comment: When it locks up try and execute a `netstat -apn` and count how many open TCP connections you have. It is possible your node.js code does not release/drop a connection due to failing to call the right close/end function. Another possibility is not handling connections that go into error (perhaps as a result of being prematurely terminated by the client).

Comment: Another possibility is that some connections get into a buggy state where they enter an infinite loop of "something", causing them to never be released, and the code for them to keep running (always / every "x" ms / on some events). The client will give up on these, but they will keep running in the server. They accumulate and accumulate, and that's what you're seeing. They setting a timeout on the socket. Also, try taking a node heap dump (several tools available) and track (over time) how many objects you have of each class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top of the flamegraph shows additional functions on the stack beyond the HTTP parser.  This shows the parser calling EventEmitter.emit(), which calls match() at native string.js, and then RegExpExecNoTests() at native regexp.js before entering v8:internal::Runtime_RegExpExec.

So what's eating the CPU is execution of a regular expression as the result of a 'data' event from the http parser.  match() is being called on an ever-growing data buffer.